# How to correct leaning dracaena

Tags: dracaena

I have a dracaena (I think a dracaena malaika) that's probably about six years old. It has been in front of a kitchen window for a while and eventually started to lean towards the light. I don't think it can stand on its own so I have tied a stake around the trunk.

I have also turned it around to attempt to get it to grow back the other way and even out the imbalance, which is slowly working, but the plant is getting a bit tall for the window now.

Is there something I can do to make this guy more sturdy?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need a longer stake, and tie it up where it starts to lean. Hopefully in time it will be strong enough to stand on its own. But for now the stem is not thick enough yet. Leaves looks very healthy! But I don't think you'll need to put it before the window anymore (unless it is a North facing window), this plant is very suitable to be placed a bit from the window. It likes a lot of light though, but indirect light is just fine, maybe just some early morning or evening direct sunlight.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. The window is not direct sun light but it is somewhat bright. I'll try moving it somewhere else with a bit less light. Maybe that will give the stem time to catch up. At this rate it's going to buckle under its own weight, which was not always the case.